# Converting centimetres to pixels to render image

Tags: interface, measurement

I have a question who Blender displays and renders the size output of an object. In Photoshop I have a canvas 500 x 500 pixels, and my image is 300 x 300 pixels. If I convert pixels to cm, I get 7.9375 cm. When I select my cube in Blender, and type in the values, the cube becomes really small in size, also my Blender canvas is 500 x 500. when I import the rendered cube in PS, its the same miniature size I see in my blender viewport. So since the conversion of pixels to cm is correct, then why does it not render it according to specific size dimensions.

The tiny cube is the result when importing it into PS.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside Blender, there is no thing as 'Object Size in pixels'. Every objects' size is calculated and stored in "Blender Units" (Assume 1 Blender Unit = 1 Meter).

The "Canvas" aka *Render Size* however, is set in px, because this is becoming an actual image. But this has nothing to do with Blender's internal length measures, so there is no point in

1. setting your canvas to cm
2. setting your image plane to px

For printing your render on paper, you need to choose a real-world "Print Size" and a "Print Resolution". Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch

Combine the print size with the resolution and you get the amount of pixels that are needed to 'fill' the paper at a certain resolution.

You can do it with this little python script. It uses Millimeter as length unit:
[image]

Just copy/paste the following code into blender's internal Text Editor, change your print size variables (and resolution if you like), then hit *Run Script*:

```
import bpy

# Specify your desired resolution and print size in x and y
dpi = 300
mm_x = 210
mm_y = 297

########  NO EDIT BELOW THIS LINE!  #############

# calculate dots per millimeter (25,4mm = 1 Inch), 
# since the print size is also given in mm.
dpmm = dpi/25.4 

# multiply print size and resolution; this will be the new resolution
new_x = mm_x * dpmm
new_y = mm_y * dpmm

# set the new values in the Output Properties UI
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = int(new_x)
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = int(new_y)
```

To wrap this all up: You now know the print size in mm and in px and you know the scaling factor by which your image plane (blue) is smaller than the 'canvas' (grey). Here the blue plane has a scale of 0.5 and the grey one has the default scale of 1.

Luckily, when the Camera's Orthographic Scale is set to 2, the render area *is exactly equal* to the size of a default cube (or Plane) with a default scale of 1 - so even if there is no 'canvas plane', we can still assume that an image plane, scaled down by some factor x, must have a final rendered pixel size equal to **x * render_size**

For example, if the canvas is 1000px, the blue plane has 0.5 scale factor, so it must be 500px.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The size of the objects in a picture is not initially tied to the image's pixel size. Instead, this relationship (DPI) is used in printing, and it is determined by the dimensions of the image and how it will eventually be printed on paper.

But, in a camera you can set up a value called Orthographic scale:

[image]

You can try to play with this value to get a result that you want.

Also you can set a different DPI in picture to have this match.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already have these values in my orthographic scale:

https://ibb.co/tLrGPbK

Regarding the DPI you mention, can you please upload a screenshot what you're referring to?

Comment: Blender doesn't care about DPI, you have no ability to set it in Blender. You can set this value in any software related to printing